# Не срабатывает интерцептор

Tags: java, java-ee

У меня есть три класса: `Main` с методом `main`, класс-интерцептор с методом-перехватчиком и класс для попытки перехватить вызов метода.

---

1.

```
package com.dugin.rostislav.test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestInterceptor().test();
    }
}
```

2.

```
package com.dugin.rostislav.test;

import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

public class SimpleInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object catchCall(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("call catched!");
        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

3.

```
package com.dugin.rostislav.test;

import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;

public class TestInterceptor {
    @Interceptors(SimpleInterceptor.class)
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Зависимость в `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

Я ожидал, что перед вызовом метода `test()`, будет вызван метод `catchCall()`, однако вызывается сразу метод `catchCall`(). Почему так происходит и как перехватить вызов?

Comment: Интерцептор сам по себе ничего не перехватывает. Это всё делает фреймвёрк, да и то только на объектах, управляемых этим фреймвёрком. Вот поставили тег java-ee, А где признаки этого java-ee в Вашей программе? Что за класс TestInterceptor? Это EJB или CDI? На других это всё даже с java-ee работать не будит! Самостоятельное приложение так вообще требует инициализации фреймвёрка на пару листов, чего в Вашем Main не заметно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поймите, аннотации сами по себе никакой магии не делают. Всегда нужен соответствующий обработчик.

JavaEE диктует чтобы все нужные обработчики были включены в сервер приложений, соответствующий сей спецификации. Самостоятельные приложения JavaEE не охватывает.

Тем не менее Вы можете задействовать тот же CDI в обычном приложении, приложив некоторые усилия. Тогда можно в принципе воспользоваться всеми прелестями фреймвёрка.

```
Weld weld = new Weld();
WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
```

Weld - одна из реализация CDI, причём единственная образцово-показательная (reference implementation)

Но при этом объекты должны управляться этим CDI. Обычно это означает, что никаких `new TestInterceptor()` не должно быть. CDI не знает Ваш `new TestInterceptor()`, не будет вызывать для него никакие интерцепторы. Он знает лишь те объекты, которые создаёт сам.

```
TestInterceptor ti = container.instance().select(TestInterceptor.class).get();
ti.test();
```

Когда новый объект создаётся через CDI, тогда CDI может перехватывать вызовы методов своего объекта. Увидев аннотацию интерцептора, он вызовет интерцептор.
На самом деле при получении объекта через CDI так или иначе происходит подмена объекта. В простейшем случае это будет прокси-объект, внешне не очень отличимый от настоящего. Методы этого прокси модифицированы таким образом, что будут вызывать интерцепторы, если они есть, и затем метод оригинального объекта.

Comment: Мдя... После библиотек, работающих на кодогенерации даже мысль в голову не закралась, что само оно не обрабатывается...